# Compiz - What effect I really don't need

Tags: 13.04, compiz

What effects I don't need but still I want to have nice 3d desktop. I want to get best performance - eyecandy balance. Can you give me some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you really "need" any effects to have a working desktop. I think this question is rather broad and you might get better answers if you can tell us your specs...

Comment: I have nVidia 6600, Athlon X64 and 2 Gb od DDR2 RAM. I know I don't need any of effects, but I just wanted to know what effects are just consuming resources but are not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

All effects are great if you like them. I soon turned them off after I installed them as they nearly all slow the computer down. I keep on some of the basic settings, otherwise I wouldn't personally bother :)

Try them all, play with them until you are happy with the feel then if you get bored, change them, and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

There was project "Beryl" ( or "Beryll" ? ) - but this project stopped.
So there is only Compiz-Fusion for that. In Ubuntu it is named "Compiz Fusion Icon"
and works together with "Cairo-Dock" resp. see at:

http://glx-dock.org/

But it is not the same like "Beryl" was.

Comment: And how is that related with my question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry overseen - but with Cairo-Dock you can adjust which effects you need / like

and which not. In Cairo-Dock you can create own Desktops and load them up as example.

Even some in 3 D !